# Отправка SMS в PDU формате

Tags: delphi, sms

Следующий код отправляет СМС в кириллице, но не весь. Примерно чуть больше половины текста.
Подскажите, где ошибка.

```
function PhoneNumberToPDU(const PhoneNumber: String): string;
var
  I: Integer;
  TempStr: string;
begin
  TempStr := PhoneNumber;
  if TempStr[1] = '+' then
    Delete(TempStr, 1, 1);
  Result := '';
  // Если длина номера нечетная, добавить 'F' в конец
  if Odd(Length(TempStr)) then
    TempStr := TempStr + 'F';
  // Поменять местами каждую пару цифр
  for I := 1 to Length(TempStr) do
    if Odd(I) then
      Result := Result + TempStr[I + 1] + TempStr[I];
end;

function EncodeText(const Text: string): string;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  for I := 1 to Length(Text) do
    Result := Result + IntToHex(Ord(Text[I]), 4);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.btnSendDPUClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  PDU, EncodedPhoneNumber, EncodedMessage: string;
  PhoneNumber, MessageText: WideString;
  AStr: AnsiString;
begin
  PhoneNumber := '+**************';
  MessageText := 'Пожалуйста, оплатите задолженность в размере ....';
  EncodedPhoneNumber := PhoneNumberToPDU(PhoneNumber);
  EncodedMessage := EncodeText(MessageText);

  PDU := '0011000C91' + EncodedPhoneNumber + '00080B' + IntToHex((Length(MessageText)), 2) + EncodedMessage;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(PDU);

  AStr  :=  'AT+CMGF=0'+ #13#10;
  BCPort1.Write(AStr[1], Length(AStr));
  Sleep(100);

  AStr  :=  'AT+CMGS=' + IntToStr((Length(PDU) div 2)-1) + #13#10;
  BCPort1.Write(AStr[1], Length(AStr));
  Sleep(100);

  AStr  :=  PDU;
  BCPort1.Write(AStr[1], Length(AStr));
  Sleep(250);

  AStr  :=  ''+#26;
  BCPort1.Write(AStr[1], Length(AStr));
  Sleep(100);
end;
```

Comment: Длина текста в СМС ограничена 160 символов латиницей или 70 - кирилицей, из-за кодирования. Для отправки длинных текстов на кириллице обычно используется разбиение его на несколько СМС.

Comment: Это понятно. Но из фразы "Пожалуйста, оплатите задолженность в размере ...." приходит только "Пожалуйста, оплатите зад". Из "Проверка кирилицы" приходит только "Проверка.". 
Методом подбора получил - PDU := '0011000C91' + EncodedPhoneNumber + '00080B' + IntToHex((Length(MessageText)*2+6), 2) + EncodedMessage; 
Так приходит весь текст. Не понял значения этих коэфициентов (*2+6)

Answer (score 0):

Помогла следующая правка:

```
procedure TfrmMain.btnSendDPUClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  PDU, EncodedPhoneNumber, EncodedMessage: string;
  PhoneNumber, MessageText: WideString;
  AStr: AnsiString;
begin
  PhoneNumber := '+**************';
  MessageText := 'Пожалуйста, оплатите задолженность в размере ....';
  EncodedPhoneNumber := PhoneNumberToPDU(PhoneNumber);
  EncodedMessage := EncodeText(MessageText);

  //PDU := '0011000C91' + EncodedPhoneNumber + '00080B' + IntToHex((Length(MessageText)), 2) + EncodedMessage;
  PDU := '0011000C91' + EncodedPhoneNumber + '00080B' + IntToHex((Length(MessageText)*2+6), 2) + EncodedMessage; //измененная строка
  Memo1.Lines.Add(PDU);

  AStr  :=  'AT+CMGF=0'+ #13#10;
  BCPort1.Write(AStr[1], Length(AStr));
  Sleep(100);

  AStr  :=  'AT+CMGS=' + IntToStr((Length(PDU) div 2)-1) + #13#10;
  BCPort1.Write(AStr[1], Length(AStr));
  Sleep(100);

  AStr  :=  PDU;
  BCPort1.Write(AStr[1], Length(AStr));
  Sleep(250);

  AStr  :=  ''+#26;
  BCPort1.Write(AStr[1], Length(AStr));
  Sleep(100);
end;
```